# Ray class group

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Can someone please go through a proof of the fact that the ray class group of a number field is finite?

I just can't find a nice readable elementary one on the internet...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to put it out there... have you considered, I don't know, a book and/or a library? There *is* a world outside the internet, after all.

Comment: You've looked at Theorem 1.7 of [Milne's notes](http://jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/cft.html)? I thought this proof was pretty clear. A more specific question on a specific proof of this fact would be warmly received here, I think. Good luck!

Comment: @Arturo: I didn't figure my question was so cripted; yes, I was asking for a source recommendation (of course, books fit into that description).

Comment: @Dylan: Thanks! Didn't know of Milne's CFT book although at the moment I'm reading his ANT :-)

Comment: @Anna: Ah, you were asking for references... That would be a different kettle of fish, indeed. But what you actually *wrote* is "can someone please **go through a proof**..." Looks like you were asking for someone to present and walk you through a proof, not to direct you to a source where you can read one.

Comment: That would have been nice too of course - btw, Thanks @ Matt, I'll go tomorrow through your post; in any case, the idea was that I was interested in a proof, so obviously references were welcome.

Answer (score 18):

The ray class group of conductor $\mathfrak m$ is defined to be the group of fractional ideals prime to $\mathfrak m$, modulo those fractional ideals which are principal, with a generator congruent to $1 \bmod \mathfrak m$.  (Here, if a real place
is contained in $\mathfrak m$, "congruenct to $1$ at such a place" is interpreted as "positive at this place".)
In symbols, write this as $I_{\mathfrak m}/P_{\mathfrak m}^1$.

It is easy to see that any ideal class admits a representative that is coprime
to $\mathfrak m$, and so the ray class group surjects onto the ideal class group.  In symbols, write $P_{\mathfrak m}$ for the principal ideals
in $I_{\mathfrak m}$; then we have the short exact sequence
$$1 \to P_{\mathfrak m}/P^1_{\mathfrak m} \to I_{\mathfrak m} /P^1_{\mathfrak m}
\to I_{\mathfrak m}/P_{\mathfrak m} \to 1.$$
The middle term is the ray class group, and, as noted, it surjects onto
the class group, which is the third term.

Since the class group is finite, to show that the ray class group is finite,
we just have to show that the first term $P_{\mathfrak m}/P^1_{\mathfrak m}$
is finite.  Luckily, this kernel is easy to compute:

If $\mathfrak a$ is a principal ideal, we can map it to its principal generator $a$.
If $a$ is $1$ mod $\mathfrak m$, then $\mathfrak a$ lies in $P^1_{\mathfrak m}$,
and so we apparently get an identifiation between $P_{\mathfrak m}/P^1_{\mathfrak m}$ and
$(\mathcal O/\mathfrak m)^{\times}.$  Actually, this is not quite
true, because $a$ is not well-defined; it is only determined up to multiplication
by a unit.  Thus actually we get an isomorphism
$$P_{\mathfrak m}/P^1_{\mathfrak m} \cong (\mathcal O/\mathfrak m)^{\times}/(\text{reduction mod }\mathfrak m \text{ of } \mathcal O^{\times}).$$
In any event, this is finite, since it is a quotient of the finite
group $(\mathcal O/\mathfrak m)^{\times}$.

[Note: if $\mathfrak m$ contains some real places $v$, then we interpret
$\mathcal O/\mathfrak m$ as denoting the product of copies of $\{\pm 1\}$
(one for each real place in $\mathfrak m$) and the usual quotient
$\mathcal O/\mathfrak m'$, where $\mathfrak m'$ is the finite part 
of $\mathfrak m$.  And of course, we interpret reduction modulo $\mathfrak m$
as being the product of the maps which attach the sign with respect to $v$ as an element in $\{\pm 1\}$, 
for each real place $v$ dividing $\mathfrak m$, and as the usual reduction
mod $\mathfrak m'$ for the finite part $\mathfrak m'$ of $\mathfrak m$.]